# Unknown Blob when pulling microsoft/xxxxx

Tags: windows, docker, nano-server

I wanted to pull the the Docker image for Windows core/nano, `docker pull microsoft/xxx` to my local computer. The pull starts but it quickly ends with the error `unknown blob`

Same result for both of these:

```
PS C:\>docker pull microsoft/nanoserver
PS C:\>docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore
```

Answer (score 3):

When trying to use images from Microsofts Docker repository "microsoft/xxx" you must ensure that you are running Docker with Windows containers, not Linux containers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10

Comment: That's kind of obvious - you can't run a container for one OS on another OS. [Docker 1.13 was released](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#/docker-for-windows-1130-2017-01-19-stable) as a stable version since this article was published, which means you can just install Docker for Windows. You can switch from Linux to HyperV containers from Docker's menu

Comment: Yes @PanagiotisKanavos , I also think it is obvious but when you use Docker on Windows as a newbie you get this error and it may confuse you. Hence I thought it worthwhile do document the question and answer here.