# How to install the windowsservercore image in docker from blob or saved file?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, windows-server-container

**Problem:**

I am unable to install the `windowsservercore` image in `docker`.

This is similar to that posed here:
[windowsservercore container image not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975252/unable-to-install-windowsservercore-container-image)

**Set-up:**

`macOS Sierra` with `Windows Server 2016 TP5` running inside `VirtualBox` alongside `docker`.

**Steps taken:**

In advance i have successfully run:

```
Install-WindowsFeature containers
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers
```

I have then run:

`docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore`

This resulted in a download and a message saying `'Unknown blob'`. I don't know where it has downloaded to or what to do with this `'Unknown blob'`.

How do i now ensure this is installed as the `windowsservercore` image for `docker` to use?

I have:

1) Re-started `docker` and run `docker images` which shows no installed images in the repository.

2) Downloaded the image file 'WindowsServerCore-10-0-14300-1000.wim' to `C:\Program Files\docker`, where i also have the `docker` and `dockerd` executables.

Can i install this image file instead? If so, how please?

Comment: Are you sure you've configured Docker to run Windows Containers and not Linux Containers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown Blob when pulling microsoft/xxxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115425/unknown-blob-when-pulling-microsoft-xxxxx)

Comment: @mason  How would I ensure I have configured Docker for Windows Containers not Linux please?

Comment: Did you look at the link I provided?

Comment: @mason Hi, i looked at the link which was very helpful. I entered the command into powershell as given at the link which resulted in an error along the lines of unknown cmdlet, incorrect path....I have docker installed at the path as shown in the original posting. Do i need to amend to reflect this path? I am executing from C:\Users\Administrator

Comment: The documentation also discussed right clicking the icon in the tray and switching it there as an alternative to use Powershell.

Comment: Not sure where tray is given I am in Windows server inside of VirtualBox. Usual place for tray is not visible.

Comment: Then try the Powershell command. All it does is invoke an exe with an argument. It's not invoking a Powershell commandlet.

Comment: I think perhaps it is because there is no CLI file in the docker folder. I have just the docker and dockerd executables in there.

Comment: Are you seeing any docker App icon? Can you try and explore options inside it?

Comment: @TarunLalwani  there is no docker app visible either which is strange. I know docker is installed as I registered the service , started the service and then did Get-Service docker as a check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to remove the existing docker and dockerd files in the docker folder and then follow exactly the instructions here: [build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container](https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/). I believe this installed the Windows-native Docker engine directly. This ensured Docker Engine was running as a Windows service.

Archive link for above:

https://web.archive.org/web/20220120042518/https://www.docker.com/blog/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/

Comment: that link doesn't seem to point to am article anymore. 

Was it similar to either of these?

https://adamtheautomator.com/docker-windows-server/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/run-your-first-container

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20220120042518/https://www.docker.com/blog/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/  @aclong